# Using progress bar?

Tags: java, android

in the application when user click on button to run new activity it have to wait some time to activity load everything and start up, till then user can see only black screen, so I want to put progress bar till activity is ready.
How can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Two links that could help you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog . Please use Google.

Comment: Try to use Asynchronous task, i may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sample code, modify this as per your code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ReadWebpageAsyncTask extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textView.setText(result);
        }
    }

    public void readWebpage(View view) {
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.vogella.de" });

    }
}
```